# Error while upgrading RabbitMq from 3.2.4 to 3.6.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I was following instruction given in the [link](http://monkeyhacks.com/post/installing-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-14-04). Updated my repository list and tried to upgrade the version but it gives the following error.
Earlier, cluster of two node of rabbitmq 3.2.4 was running.

**Error:**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rabbitmq-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 467 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.6.1-1) ...
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                                                                                      * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
                                                                                                                                        [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


  [1]: http://monkeyhacks.com/post/installing-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

In the error log i am getting this :

```
Cluster upgrade needed but other nodes are running [add_ip_to_listener,
                                                    exchange_decorators,
                                                    exchange_event_serial,gm,
                                                    mirrored_supervisor,
                                                    policy_apply_to,
                                                    queue_decorators,
                                                    remove_user_scope,
                                                    semi_durable_route,
                                                    topic_trie,
                                                    topic_trie_node,
                                                    user_admin_to_tags]
and I want [add_ip_to_listener,cluster_name,exchange_event_serial,gm,
            internal_system_x,mirrored_supervisor,policy_apply_to,
            recoverable_slaves,remove_user_scope,semi_durable_route,
            topic_trie,topic_trie_node,user_admin_to_tags,
            user_password_hashing]
```

Comment: Is RabbitMQ currently running? You may need to stop the queue and start after upgrade if it's trying to get handles on nodes.

Comment: @BookOfGreg No, from the cluster one of the node is down. Broker is not able to start